# ASP.NET Open popup and then redirect

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have my custom css/html popup lightbox and a form with a button on it.

My goal is, when you press a button:

1. open this popup
2. then `Thread.Sleep`
3. and after that `Response.Redirect` to another page.

Is this possible?

Here is my html code:

```
<a href="#test"><img src="images/smallimg.jpg"/></a>
<div class="overlay" id="test">
<img src="images/bigimg.jpg"/>
<a href="#page" class="close">x Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `Thread.Sleep` to delay a `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: Where is your code for invoking the popup?

Comment: What is the purpose of the popup if you going to redirect? Is it some kind of a message that you  want the user to see for  a while and then redirect?

Comment: Yep, I want to show welcome message and then redirect. And I don't have code for invoking the popup. Is this makes with js?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in JavaScript, First Show the popup and then use setTimeout(code,millisec,lang) function to activate the ButtonClick event/function.

In ASP.NET bind the setTimeout(code,millisec,lang) function through back end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing all of this work in JavaScript, then it seems silly to call the server to have the main thread sleep for x seconds and then redirect when it can all be done in JavaScript.

Show the box, then add this JavaScript to create a delay (5 seconds in this example; it is 5000 milliseconds) and redirect to another page:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = 'OtherPage.aspx';
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script

```
alert(YourMessage);
location.replace(YourPageName);
```

or in your case

```
$('.overlay').show(); // here you need to use proper style for your div to show as a popup
location.replace(YourPageName);
```

Or you can use also jQuery Dialog.

if you find any problem let me know